# Capture python output from nested bash call?

Tags: python, bash, stdout

I have a few python functions that print some output status messages. I then have a bash script, `run_python.sh` that calls these python scripts in order and has the `set -e` parameter within it so it fails if anything fails. I need to call that script (run_python.sh) with a list of parameters and I wanted to capture the output of all those things

So I have `call_run_python.sh` that calls run_python with parameters.

run like this `call_run_python.sh 2>&1 | tee log.txt`

My only issue is that now I don't get the output of the python scripts in the output. Is there some additional redirecting that needs to be done? I get the output from the `echo` statements within `run_python.sh` but none of the python output called from the same script

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following to cause the output to not be buffered

```
stdbuf -o 0 python test.py 2>&1 |  tee out1.txt
```

(see: https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/UnacceptableSlateblueStack)